Necessary and sufficient conditions for Collocation methods based on Butcher Tableau
I am interested in determining under what conditions a Runge-Kutta method becomes a Collocation method based on its Butcher table.
Now I know that you can calculate the coefficients of the $A$ matrix and the $b$ vector using
$$\begin{aligned}
    a_{ij} &= \int_0^{c_i} l_j(\tau) \text{d}\tau\\
    b_i &= \int_0^1 l_i(\tau) \text{d}\tau
\end{aligned}$$
(see, e.g., "Geometric numerical integration: structure-preserving algorithms for ordinary differential equations", p.31 by Hairer & Wanner) for a set of Lagrange basis polynomials $l_i(\tau)$ and (given) collocation points $c_i,\ i=1,...,s$ to obtain a collocation method, where $s$ is the number of stages.
But I want to know if there is a set of necessary and sufficient conditions to determine if a given Runge Kutta method is a Collocation method based on its Butcher table.
I assume that this involves the simplifying assumptions
$$\begin{aligned}
    B(p) &= \sum_{j=1}^sb_jc_j^{k-1}= \frac{1}{k},\quad k=1,...,p\\
    C(q) &= \sum_{j=1}^sa_{ij}c_j^{k-1}= \frac{c_i^k}{k},\quad k=1,...,q,\, i=1,…,s
\end{aligned}$$
For example, in "Solving Ordinary Differential Equations II. Stiff and Differential-Algebraic Problems", p.75 by Hairer & Wanner it is stated that

The coefficients $a_{ij}$ are defined by $C(s)$ for the Lobatto IIIA methods.
It is therefore a collocation method.

But there is no explanation why that must be so.
Furthermore, I found the following quote in Butcher's "Numerical Methods for Ordinary Differential Equations" on p.265:

In the case of methods satisfying the collocation condition $C(s)$, $B(s)$ [...]

This also implies $C(s), B(s)$ are necessary (and sufficient?) conditions for a method to be a collocation method.
But he fails to mention why these are collocation conditions and why they should hold for a collocation method and if they are sufficient.
My question is: Are $C(s), B(s)$ necessary and sufficient conditions for a Runge-Kutta method to be a collocation method?
If $C(s),B(s)$ are the desired conditions I seek, this would imply that neither Radau IA methods (constructed with $C(s-1)$) nor Lobatto IIIB/C/C* methods (constructed with $C(s-2)$, $C(s-1)$, and $C(s-1)$, respectively) are collocation methods.

Acutally, in "Geometric numerical integration: structure-preserving algorithms for ordinary differential equations" by Hairer and Wanner on p.32, i.e., a little further down the line w.r.t. the reference above it is said that the simplifying assumptions are equivalent to the integrals above due to the relation $$\tau^{k-1}=\sum_{j=1}^sc_j^{k-1}l_j(\tau)$$
How to arrive at this condition and the conclusion is unclear to me.
But just accepting this is true means that the simplifying assumptions are at least necessary for a collocation method.
